# Mocha + Chai + Puppeteer Testing Response Hangs The Tests

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, puppeteer, chai

```
it('Successfully Fetch Numbers',async(done)=>{
    page.on('response', response => {
        if (response.url().endsWith("allspecialnumbers"))
        {
         
            try {
                expect(response.status()).to.equal(200);
                done();

            }catch (err){
                console.log(err);
                done(err)

            }
        }
    })
    await page.$eval('#getsmsspecialnumbers_btn', el => el.click());
});
```

**This tests hangs the code and on console the test is highlighted red without any error message.**
I am using chai, mocha and puppeteer
EDIT:
I consoled this.currentTest

```
afterEach(function(){
    if (this.currentTest.state !== 'passed'){
        console.log("Faied",this.currentTest)
    }
})
```

and in err I have

```
err: <ref *3> Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.` comes from Mocha. The reason is that your test

```
it('Successfully Fetch Numbers',async(done)=>{
```

is both an async function (which always returns a Promise), but also takes `done` callback. You should pick one of these.

For example, if you pick callback-style, you could just remove `async` and `await` (and maybe add `.catch(done)` to ensure any promise rejections are converted to callback).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have a question I need done in page.on('reponse',fn') to make sure that tests is done only when i get the response. So If i remove async from the function then what should i do about `await page.$eval('#getsmsspecialnumbers_btn', el => el.click());`

Comment: Just leave it as `page.$eval(...)` - although the function returns immediately (since there's no `await`), that's correct here - the test is not done until the callback `done` has been called.

Comment: Thanks Alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Pasi**. Your answer helped solve my posted issue. But I encountered many other issues till my task was completed. So I tempered my code here and there and this below is my final code that did my work.

```
responseEventHandlerWrapper(page,done,urlEndsWith,checkError,ExpectThis) {

return async function responseEventHandler(response) {

    if (response.url().endsWith(urlEndsWith))
    {
        try {
            let result  = await response.json();
            (ExpectThis.constructor.name == 'AsyncFunction')?
            await ExpectThis(checkError ? result.error : result.payload):
                ExpectThis(checkError ? result.error : result.payload);
            page.removeListener('response',responseEventHandler);
            done();
        }
        catch (err){
            page.removeListener('response',responseEventHandler);
            done(err)
        }
    }

};
```

}

Then in my test

```
it('(Login Successful', (done) => {

    let urlEndsWith = "login";

   //Steps For Login Process Are Performed Here

    page.on('response', responseEventHandlerWrapper(
        page,
        done,
        urlEndsWith,
        true,
        async (error)=> {
            expect(error).to.be.oneOf([null]);
        }
    ));
});
```